# How do I validate my MVC viewmodel to not accept hexadecimal numbers for integers?

Tags: c#, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 with Razor Views. I have the following field in my viewmodel:

```
[Range(1 to 500)]
public int? MyNumber { get; set; }
```

If I enter `#125` on the corresponding web form and submit, the value is interpreted as a hexadecimal number and converted to its decimal equivalent (I am guessing this happens during model binding). As long as the converted number passes the range test, it passes validation.

The value in the raw request is `%23125`. By the time the viewmodel gets it, it has become `293`.

Are there any model annotations or other server-side validation techniques that can catch this?

So far I have tried working with a non-nullable integer and a regex attribute. Neither have worked.

Comment: This is just an idea (I've not even checked to see if it would work) but could you look in the raw request object and compare the value in the request against the value in the model. I suspect you might see the string version of what is submitted instead of the converted Model version in which case you could check for symbols such as #.

Comment: I added some details. I suppose I could use JS to strip certain values from all integer fields (is that what you were suggesting?), but that would not protect me in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

If the hex is being converted during model binding as you suspect, you will need to add some validation on the client to prevent non-integer values from being entered in the field.  Ideally, all validation is performed on both the client and server.

The client validation could be something as simple as the "pattern" attribute with an integer only regex.  On the server you could add the RegularExpressionAttribute to the property with the following regex (accepting any positive integer):

Client validation:

```
<form>
    <label>Your int: 
      <input type="text" pattern="^[1-9]\d*$" required />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Server validation:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]\d*$", ErrorMessage = "Only integer values are allowed.")]
[Range(1 to 500)]
public int? MyNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried and failed with a different regex; I'll give this one a try. Unfortunately I'll have to wait until after the weekend to see if it works. Wait... Yay, it's the weekend! I have to get my priorities straight.

Comment: Apparently no validation on the model will work because the value has already been converted. I figured out another way.

Answer (score 0):

The only server-side method appears to be a **custom model binder**. I also had to add handling for special characters that MVC considers dangerous. The solution I came up with is posted below:

**In Global.asax (Application_Start):**

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
```

**New Class:**

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result;

        try
        {
            result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"The field {bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayName} contains bad data.");
            return bindingContext.Model;
        }

        if (bindingContext.ModelName == "MyNumber" || bindingContext.ModelName == "MyNumber2")
        {
            return StripAndBindModel(bindingContext, result);
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    private object StripAndBindModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ValueProviderResult result)
    {
        var strippedInput = result.AttemptedValue.Replace("#", string.Empty);

        int value;

        if (int.TryParse(strippedInput, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"The field {bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayName} must be a valid number.");
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, result);

        return bindingContext.Model;
    }
}
```